# How to Invoke and Kill Executable in TFS Build Definition?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-definition

I am developing a Web API solution. This EXE listens and responds to localhost:8080/abc/.

I have developed a Test solution for this executable.These tests simply verify responses from localhost:8080/abc/.

I have already successfully created a build definition that:

1. Gets and compiles the solution.
2. Gets and compiles the tests.
3. Runs the tests.

My problem here is, the tests are failing, because the EXE isn't up and running. How do I bring up the EXE for the tests, and kill it after the tests are done? Could this be done solely in the build definition itself? Say via MSBuild Arguments in the "Build process parameters"? Hopefully there is a simple solution to this...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can't manage to solve this in the build definition alone.

I found the solution in modifying the build template (via Edit Build Definition... -> Process), by adding InvokeProcess controls in the build flow. Have these controls call BAT files that instead run / kill the EXE.